# NetworkOnMainThread error still

Tags: android, network-programming

I am experimenting with firebase and want to read a textfile from the bucket. I can copy the file to local disk, which works fine. Now I want to read the textfile and copy the contents to an arraylist. This time I get the NetworkOnMainThread although I start a new thread to do the work. At least I think I am.I read about using Asynchtask, but would like to know WHY this is not working as expected. The code to get the InputstreamfromURL worked fine in the past.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_download);
    downloadtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.downloadtext);
    text = new ArrayList<>();
    listViewText = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewtext);
    listViewText.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, text));

    Thread thread= new Thread(){
        public void run() {
            storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
            storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://fir-test-68815.appspot.com");
            filename = "testfile.txt";
            StorageReference file = storageRef.child(filename);

            file.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "URL =" + uri.toString());
                    try {
                        InputStream is = getInputStreamFromURL(uri);
                        text = getText(is);
                        textReady.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                ((ArrayAdapter)listViewText.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });


        }
        private ArrayList<String> getText(InputStream is) throws IOException {
            ArrayList<String> text = new ArrayList<>();
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                text.add(line);
            }
            return text;
        }

        private InputStream getInputStreamFromURL(Uri urlToGet) throws IOException {
            InputStream is = null;
            URL downloadURL = new URL(urlToGet.toString());
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) downloadURL.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Starts the query
            conn.connect();
// next two lines produce the error
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
            is = conn.getInputStream();
            return is;
        }
    };
    thread.start();
    textReady = new Handler();

}
```

Comment: Make a Service responsible for this

Comment: Will do. Just try to understand firebase for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase event callbacks are [by default invoked on the main UI thread](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/index.html?com/firebase/client/Config.html). That also happens with your `OnSuccessListener`.

There are also [other ways to download files with Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files). But if you still want to use `getDownloadUrl()`, you'll need to implement the downloading on a separate thread (for example using `AsyncTask`) after `getDownloadUrl()` callback fires.